# O que é indexação baseada em zero? Indexação de arrays de base zero? Numeração baseada em 0

Tags: array, terminologia

Consultando a documentação do comando [substring do sql-server](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Existe o seguinte termo: `A numeração é baseada em 1`. Diante disso veio a dúvida.

O que significa este termo?

Desejo saber mais sobre essa abordagem de indexação utilizada em linguagens de programação em geral. Porque é utilizada indexação baseada em zero?

E indexação baseada em um?

Existem outras possibilidades de indexação?

Comment: Meu chute é que começar em zero teve influência do C (que tem motivos práticos pra isso) e do [famoso artigo do Dijkstra](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html). Tem também uma discussão interessante [aqui](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/110804).